# What is a flash message in Passport?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm reading the Passport documentation and I would like to know what a flash message is.
Googeling it isn't giving me any relevant answer.

Answer (score 3):

Flash message are like temporary variable

But it's mainly a Temporary session, For example you want to show an error message only for once , It'll be available for only one hit.  in you next route it will be gone

So by using the flash message you can show error or success messages to user.

Answer (score 3):

To paraphrase the passport.js docs, Flash messages are combined with route redirects to provide or display status information to the user.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

You basically need them to let the user know they had either failed or succeeded in accessing some resource.

The following are snippets provided in the docs:

**In case of a failure**

```
passport.authenticate('local', { failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.' });
```

**In case of a success**

```
passport.authenticate('local', { successFlash: 'Welcome!' });
```

Answer (score 2):

The most basic flash setup uses something like [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash).  It's basically a messaging system that utilizes the session for temporary storage.

The basic tutorials I've ran through for it use it for messages like toast popups.  Once the user acknowledges the message, it is cleared from the session.